# Form validation React function component with useState

Tags: reactjs, use-state

I am working on the client-side validation form with React using a component function and useState. the problem is that when I click submit, the handleSubmit updates the "validation" states with the errors, but they are not render when the state changes. they are rendered only when I input some values on the input fields. How could I fix this?

bellow you can find the code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

function RegistrationView() {
  const [inputValues, setInputValue] = useState({
    fName: '',
    lName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
  });

  const [validation, setValidation] = useState({
    fName: '',
    lName: '',
    email: '',
    password: '',
    confirmPassword: '',
  });

  //handle submit updates
  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setInputValue({ ...inputValues, [name]: value });
  }

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    let errors = validation;

    //first Name validation
    if (!inputValues.fName.trim()) {
      errors.fName = 'First name is required';
    } else {
      errors.fName = '';
    }
    //last Name validation
    if (!inputValues.lName.trim()) {
      errors.lName = 'Last name is required';
    } else {
      errors.lName = '';
    }

    // email validation
    const emailCond =
      "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/";
    if (!inputValues.email.trim()) {
      errors.email = 'Email is required';
    } else if (!inputValues.email.match(emailCond)) {
      errors.email = 'Please ingress a valid email address';
    } else {
      errors.email = '';
    }

    //password validation
    const cond1 = '/^(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$/';
    const cond2 = '/^(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/';
    const cond3 = '/^(?=.*[0-9]).{6,20}$/';
    const password = inputValues.password;
    if (!password) {
      errors.password = 'password is required';
    } else if (password.length < 6) {
      errors.password = 'Password must be longer than 6 characters';
    } else if (password.length >= 20) {
      errors.password = 'Password must shorter than 20 characters';
    } else if (!password.match(cond1)) {
      errors.password = 'Password must contain at least one lowercase';
    } else if (!password.match(cond2)) {
      errors.password = 'Password must contain at least one capital letter';
    } else if (!password.match(cond3)) {
      errors.password = 'Password must contain at least a number';
    } else {
      errors.password = '';
    }

    //matchPassword validation
    if (!inputValues.confirmPassword) {
      errors.confirmPassword = 'Password confirmation is required';
    } else if (inputValues.confirmPassword !== inputValues.Password) {
      errors.confirmPassword = 'Password does not match confirmation password';
    } else {
      errors.password = '';
    }

    return setValidation(errors);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className='sign-up-form'>
        <form
          id='registrationForm'
          action='/'
          method='POST'
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <div className='form-control'>
            <input
              placeholder='First Name'
              type='string'
              name='fName'
              id='fName'
              className='input-field'
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.fName}
            />
            {validation.fName && <p>{validation.fName}</p>}
            {validation.fName && console.log(validation)}
          </div>
          <div className='form-control'>
            <input
              placeholder='Last Name'
              type='string'
              id='lName'
              name='lName'
              className='input-field'
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.lName}
            />
            {validation.lName && <p>{validation.lName}</p>}
          </div>
          <div className='form-control'>
            <input
              placeholder='email'
              type='email'
              name='email'
              className='input-field'
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.email}
            />
          </div>
          {validation.email && <p>{validation.email}</p>}

          <div className='form-control'>
            <input
              placeholder='password'
              type='password'
              name='password'
              className='input-field'
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.password}
              required
            />
            {validation.password && <p>{validation.password}</p>}
          </div>
          <div className='form-control'>
            <input
              placeholder='confirm password'
              type='password'
              name='confirmPassword'
              className='input-field'
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.confirmPassword}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button type='submit' id='submit-button'>
            submit
          </button>
          <span className='form-input-login'>
            Already have an account? Login <a href='#'>here</a>
          </span>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RegistrationView;
```

thanks

Comment: Do I understand you correctly that you want to validate while the user is typing and instead of after submission? If yes, then put the if statements and setValidation from handleSubmit to handleChange.

Answer (score 5):

You can put the validation logic in a separate function and invoke it when textInput changes using  an `useEffect` hook. I hope this helps. You can improve the validation logic further any way you want .

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function RegistrationView() {
  const [inputValues, setInputValue] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const [validation, setValidation] = useState({
    fName: "",
    lName: "",
    email: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  //handle submit updates
  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setInputValue({ ...inputValues, [name]: value });
  }

  const checkValidation = () => {
    let errors = validation;

    //first Name validation
    if (!inputValues.fName.trim()) {
      errors.fName = "First name is required";
    } else {
      errors.fName = "";
    }
    //last Name validation
    if (!inputValues.lName.trim()) {
      errors.lName = "Last name is required";
    } else {
      errors.lName = "";
    }

    // email validation
    const emailCond =
      "/^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+(?:.[a-zA-Z0-9-]+)*$/";
    if (!inputValues.email.trim()) {
      errors.email = "Email is required";
    } else if (!inputValues.email.match(emailCond)) {
      errors.email = "Please ingress a valid email address";
    } else {
      errors.email = "";
    }

    //password validation
    const cond1 = "/^(?=.*[a-z]).{6,20}$/";
    const cond2 = "/^(?=.*[A-Z]).{6,20}$/";
    const cond3 = "/^(?=.*[0-9]).{6,20}$/";
    const password = inputValues.password;
    if (!password) {
      errors.password = "password is required";
    } else if (password.length < 6) {
      errors.password = "Password must be longer than 6 characters";
    } else if (password.length >= 20) {
      errors.password = "Password must shorter than 20 characters";
    } else if (!password.match(cond1)) {
      errors.password = "Password must contain at least one lowercase";
    } else if (!password.match(cond2)) {
      errors.password = "Password must contain at least one capital letter";
    } else if (!password.match(cond3)) {
      errors.password = "Password must contain at least a number";
    } else {
      errors.password = "";
    }

    //matchPassword validation
    if (!inputValues.confirmPassword) {
      errors.confirmPassword = "Password confirmation is required";
    } else if (inputValues.confirmPassword !== inputValues.Password) {
      errors.confirmPassword = "Password does not match confirmation password";
    } else {
      errors.password = "";
    }

    setValidation(errors);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    checkValidation();
  }, [inputValues]);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div className="sign-up-form">
        <form
          id="registrationForm"
          action="/"
          method="POST"
          onSubmit={handleSubmit}
        >
          <div className="form-control">
            <input
              placeholder="First Name"
              type="string"
              name="fName"
              id="fName"
              className="input-field"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.fName}
            />
            {validation.fName && <p>{validation.fName}</p>}
            {validation.fName && console.log(validation)}
          </div>
          <div className="form-control">
            <input
              placeholder="Last Name"
              type="string"
              id="lName"
              name="lName"
              className="input-field"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.lName}
            />
            {validation.lName && <p>{validation.lName}</p>}
          </div>
          <div className="form-control">
            <input
              placeholder="email"
              type="email"
              name="email"
              className="input-field"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.email}
            />
          </div>
          {validation.email && <p>{validation.email}</p>}

          <div className="form-control">
            <input
              placeholder="password"
              type="password"
              name="password"
              className="input-field"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.password}
              required
            />
            {validation.password && <p>{validation.password}</p>}
          </div>
          <div className="form-control">
            <input
              placeholder="confirm password"
              type="password"
              name="confirmPassword"
              className="input-field"
              onChange={(e) => handleChange(e)}
              value={inputValues.confirmPassword}
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="submit-button">
            submit
          </button>
          <span className="form-input-login">
            Already have an account? Login <a href="#">here</a>
          </span>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default RegistrationView;
```

Comment: thanks I'll take a look at it!

Answer (score 1):

You can try clone with seperate operator.

```
let errors = {...validation}
```

Or you can use react-hook-form library. It's easy to use and very isolated.

[react hook form](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register)

Comment: Awesome! it works! thank you! Can I ask you why it work this way??

Comment: In javascript, object and functions are non-primitive type. this means, if you assign object to another variable, in memory both variables point same variable. With Seperate operator(...) you can clone content of object instead of reference. you can look this article: https://www.edureka.co/blog/data-types-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

As mark on your code, errors set validation base on call by reference, so after set state not render the component. Please try to deep clone your error like below as.

```
 let errors = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(validation));
```

I hope it will work for you. Thanks

Comment: Thank you! it works!